# What is the 'third heaven'?

Tags: niv

In 2 Corinthians 12:1-3,  Paul talks about one's experience with the 'third heaven'.

> I must go on boasting. Although there is nothing to be gained.  I will go on to visions and revaluations from the Lord.  I know a man in Christ who fourteen years ago was caught up in the third heaven.  Whether it was in the body or out of the body,  I don't know -  God knows. - 2 Corinthians 1-3 (niv)

What is the third heaven spoken about here?